# python: which file is newer & by how much time

Tags: python, comparison, timedelta

I am trying to create a filedate comparison routine. I suspect that the following is a rather clunky approach.

I had some difficulty finding info about timedelta's attributes or methods, or whatever they are called; hence, I measured the datetime difference below only in terms of days, minutes and seconds, and there is no list item representing years.

Any suggestions for an alternative, would be much appreciated.

```
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import sys

def datetime_filedif(filepath1e, filepath2e):
    filelpath1 = str(filepath1e)
    filepath1 = str(filepath1e)
    filepath2 = str(filepath2e)

    filepath1_lmdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filepath1))
    filepath2_lmdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filepath2))

    td_files = filepath2_lmdate - filepath1_lmdate #Time delta of the 2 filedates
    td_list = [('td_files.days', td_files.days), ('td_hrs', int(str(td_files.seconds))/3600), ('td_minutes', (int(str(td_files.seconds))%3600)/60), ('td_seconds', (int(str(td_files.seconds))%3600)%60)]

    print "Line 25: ", str(td_list)

    return td_list
```

Comment: hard to tell really. what type are filepath1e and filepath2e?

Answer (score 10):

There is a solution for that already:

```
import os
modified_time = os.stat(path).st_mtime # time of most recent content modification
diff_time = os.stat(path_1).st_mtime - os.stat(path_2).st_mtime
```

Now you have the time in seconds since Epoch. why are you creating a new representation, you can create a deltatime or whatever from this, why invent a new format?