# Check if the file is newer then some other file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python: which file is newer & by how much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297003/python-which-file-is-newer-by-how-much-time)

In python -- how do I check -- if the file is newer then some other file?

**Edit**:

There are creation time and modification time.

The question should state the desired property explicitly.

## Modification

- `os.stat(FILE).st_mtime`
- `os.path.getmtime(FILE)`

## Creation

`os.path.getctime(FILE)` and `os.stat(FILE).st_ctime` doesn't give creation time on Unix-like OSes. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946967/get-file-creation-time-with-python-on-mac) by [root](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1199589/root) has the solution on how to find out the creation time on Unix-like boxes.

Comment: What have you tried so far? File operations like this usually are easily solved with the [`os` module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh I was thinking what module to search. Now I'm reading the doc of os.stat -- thatnks to You.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it's not a duplicate of that -- since there people talk about modification time, while the question as it stated -- is about creation time (frankly speaking modification -- is what I need -- but I forgotten all about it while posting the question).

Comment: Well, since you *changed* your question it is now no longer a duplicate. The other question showed you how to retrieve that information, and that was your original question as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use `os.path.getctime`. This example will return `True` if `file1` was created before `file2` and `False` otherwise.

```
import os.path
os.path.getctime('file1') < os.path.getctime('file2')
```

EDIT: Note that [there is no cross platform solution to your question](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) -- ctime() in Unix means last change time, not create time. [The same applies when using os.stat(file).st_ctime.](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.stat#os.stat)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946967/get-file-creation-time-with-python-on-mac) seems to be something that could work on unix machines.

Comment: Fortunately I don't have to deal with Windows.

Comment: @ Adobe -- updated the answer adding a link to another question about OSX , but it seems to be a bit hackish.

Answer (score 15):

```
import os
f1 = os.path.getmtime('file1')
f2 = os.path.getmtime('file2')

if f1 > f2:
```

check for modified time might be one solution

Comment: It seems that you are comparing the modification time, not creation.

Comment: Because file can be update to be newer

Comment: It is good to be aware that if the file doesn't exist this throws an OSError.  Would be good to wrap in try / except block.

Answer (score 4):

Using `os.stat` on any file, gives you a set of 10 different stats about your file.. One of the stat is `creation time` -> `st_ctime` .. You can use that to calculate the difference between your creation time of two files..

```
>>> import os
>>> os.stat("D:\demo.pl")
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, 
st_gid=0, st_size=135L, st_atime=1348227875L, st_mtime=1348228036L, 
st_ctime=1348227875L)

>>> os.stat("D:\demo.pl").st_ctime
1348227875.8448658
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def comp(path1, path2):    
    return os.stat(path1).st_ctime > os.stat(path2).st_ctime
```